# Hibernate One-to-One foreign key using xml Not deleting orphan

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have two classes A and B.

```
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="A_ID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" column="NAME"/>

    <many-to-one name="B" cascade="all"
                 column="B_ID" unique="true"/>

</class>
```

```
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="B">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="n" column="N"/>

</class>
```

A.setB(new B());
When I save it works fine.

when I remove the record. A.setB(null);
I see a orphan record. 
I see in A Table the column for B is null but on B Table there is still a record.

I tried to look in other solutions but couldnot find the ans to this.

Comment: you want the orphanRemoval="true" property... but your mapping is a bit weird. i mean you have many A to one B and you want that if any A entity remove relationship to B, B need to be deleted? and all the other A that still has relation with B?

Comment: I am trying to do one-to-one mapping using foriegn key. So I have used many-to-one instance

Comment: well orphan removal is the way... but that is not a one-to-one mapping then

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone In this section 5.1.13. One-to-one says we can use many-to-one mapping for unique foreign key

Comment: calling Update method. when I add orphan removal gives - java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry.getLoadedValue(EntityEntry.java:255)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:232)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:127)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:376)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpd